Clone and download huggingface model hub to cache
I want to create a docker container for running huggingface models. These models are downloaded as the container runs. But to speed up the container I would really like to have them already in cache before the container runs. I can't dry run the container because of the way mounting works during docker compose. So what I would really like to do is dry run the container as-is, take a snapshot of the .cache/huggingface-hub status and then redownload that stuff using huggingface CLI. Is there a way to make this happen?
Essentially my question is: Is there a pip freeze and pip -r requriements.txt for huggingface CLI?
